# Solubility of turmeric powder

Tags: spices, cocktails

I wonder if anyone mixes turmeric in milk, almond milk or water, and if you still have those insoluble bits interfering in the beverage.

What I've been doing is mixing milk, turmeric powder, honey and vanilla together, then filtering it through a very fine strainer (something you might use for straining curdled milk). However this process is tedious.

I was wondering if I'm one of the few that has this problem, and most people have access to a soluble kind of turmeric.

Comment: I wonder, what are you making with this interesting ingredient?

Comment: @Hizki, it's a cool drink, actually. You can use almond milk or cow's milk. The turmeric and honey interact perfectly in the drink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turmeric is a plant, and therefore is made up of many different chemicals. Most of the aromatic compounds in turmeric are either water-soluble or disperse well in water, and are too small to be strained out.
The rest is the actual plant matter -cellulose, proteins etc., which is not and can not be water soluble.

You are not the only person to experience this, and there is no such thing as soluble turmeric.
One thing you may want to try is turmeric flavouring (e.g. http://www.epigenetics-international.com/product/24/Turmeric_Root_Flavouring_100ml/) . This is an alcoholic solution of natural turmeric extract, which you may be able to make yourself if you felt so inclined.

Comment: I wonder if that removes the medical properties of turmeric?

Answer (score 1):

Here in Indonesia we fine grate the turmeric root, ideally using the old "mother' the bit that is oldest from the clump. It has the most medicinal effect and the strongest colour. Water is passed through the gratings and they are squeezed till the last drop comes out. In some cooking the grated root is used. The colour stains clothes and the hands.

Comment: Hi @Steve Mudoch. How long do you store your turmeric brew?

Comment: The fresh turmeric brew is used the day its made (24 hours) without change in character. We put ours in the refrigerator and it keeps three days.